# Convert date to string in impala

Tags: string, date, type-conversion, impala

I have a column which is a date in the following format : 2018-04-28.

I try to convert it in Impala but it seems there is no way it lets me operate on it at all. I know it doesn't support date formats but it won't even let me convert it.

I've tried to use things like the following but nothing works :

```
SELECT unix_timestamp(cast(t1.`date` as string),'yyyy-MM-dd') FROM example
```

Even `cast(t1.`date`as string)` won't work. I always get the same error :

```
AnalysisException: Unsupported type 'DATE' in 't1.`date`'.
```

Would anyone know a way to convert this ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

First use DATE_FORMAT to convert datetime

Answer (score 0):

if  you use impala  please set your date-column type  to `timestamp`  impala support timestamp much well than date .  the time stamp String format should be like `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`

I tried  your SQL it works well when change  `date` to `timeStamp`

the date type might be a bug  in impala.